# Synergy sharing mouse

Tags: synergy

I have ran into sharing mouse problem while testing to run between vms.

First of all, my lab is below.
1. Windows 7 Guest OS on ESXi VM.
2. The vm is running on Teradici via PCoIP Protocal.

I have 2 teradici zero clients (NC241) and synergy 1.6.2 version installed them. 1 zero client is responsibility for server role and another one is for client.

The configuration has been completed and 2 synergy were properly connected. It is no problem so far.

However, when the cursor is moved to next zero client, the cursor was moved faster than I controlled and  it is ramdomly moved. Sometimes disappeared.

Anybody else knows or has experienced about this issue?
Please help me ):

Comment: I am having this problem as well. Did you ever find a solution?